# Import a variable into a C program from a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am required to make some changes in an existing long C source code. There is a top-level Makefile which defines the various compiler options like directory locations of libraries used by the linker.

Something like :

```
LD_OPTIONS = $(PATH_TO_MYLIB1) $(PATH_TO_MYLIB2)
```

Now, I am thinking of using `dlsym()` and `dlopen()` to use these libraries instead of linking them explicitly. For this, I need the library path.

```
dlopen( path_to_lib , RTLD_NOW) ;
```

How can I use the `PATH_TO_LIB` variable from the Makefile and use it in my program? I thought of using something like "`echo` with `system()`". However, it is my expectation that there are better solutions. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your makefile you can write

```
CFLAGS += -DPATH_TO_LIB="somepath/somelib"
```

so `PATH_TO_LIB` becomes preprocessor macro you can use in your source like

```
dlopen(PATH_TO_LIB, RTLD_NOW);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't much see the point of your change if your paths are hardcoded anyway, but I digress. You could do something like this:

In the makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -DMYLIB_1=$(PATH_TO_MYLIB1) -DMYLIB_2=$(PATH_TO_MYLIB2)
```

Then in your souce:

```
dlopen(MYLIB_1, RTLD_NOW);
```

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this perhaps?

In your code

```
#ifndef PATH_TO_LIB
#error Path to ImportantLib missing
#endif ...
```

and the compile command might look
 like:

```
 cc -DPATH_TO_LIB=\"${PATH_TO_LIB}\"
```

Comment: If you're going to do something like that, it's probably better to do a #warning or #error inside the #ifndef block rather than just assigning it to some arbitrary value which will break at runtime (perhaps much later, since we never know when/if/ever this dlopen() will be called)

Comment: I don't thing the whole "ifndef ... error" thing is really needed. If macro isn't defined, you get "unresolved symbol PATH_TO_LIB" linker error anyway.